# why do the assignment statement in cycle only executes once in python

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I think it is different from C language habits in mine.
I want to excute assignment statement every times, so how to do it?

input

```py
a = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
for i in range(6):
    b = a
    print(len(b))
    c = b.pop(i)
```

output

```py
6
5
4
3
Exception has occurred: IndexError
pop index out of range
```

It seems like `b = a` only excute once.

the answer that I want to get is:

```py
6
6
6
6
6
6
```

I do not want to change `b` length.

Comment: I delete `import numpy as np`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you're not using `numpy`, so no need to import it.

Second, what you think of as "assignment" doesn't really exist in Python. Rather, you are binding the *name* `b` to the value that `a` is also bound to. In practical terms, there is no difference between your code and this:

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
for i in range(6):
    print(len(a))
    c = a.pop(i)
```

If you want a copy, you need to explicitly create one:

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
for i in range(6):
    b = a[:]  # or b = a.copy()
    print(len(b))
    c = b.pop(i)
```

Output:

```
6
6
6
6
6
6
```

Answer (score 1):

`a` and `b` aren't different objects, they are just different names for the same object. When you say `b.pop(i)`, you are modifying that one object that both `a` and `b` point to, so doing `b=a` doesn't do anything past the first iteration; `b` is already pointing to the same object as `a`. What you want to do can be done by doing `b=a.copy()`.